# Force document(s) into SOLR search results

Tags: search, solr

Is there a way to force specific documents into SOLR search results?

I'm trying something like this but is not working:

`/q=id:21321 OR myNormalSearchConditionsHereIncludingDismaxQUery`

My goal is to have certain documents always show up in some search results, no matter what the query is.

Comment: Could you provide more details as to why this query is not working?

Comment: The query shows my normal results but it's not adding the document I need injected into them.

Comment: I ended up making a second separate request to SOLR and cached it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Solr [MoreLikeThis component](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/MoreLikeThis)

This is just a quick thought i would make from your description.
With this you will no longer require a second query and caching the results.

Comment: Thanks Rajesh. I don't see how MLT would work here, my goal is to get the normal search results and insert into them completely unrelated documents. In any case, the separate requested worked a lot better, as I was able to randomize the position of the inserted documents, which proved to be an extra requirement.